# How to absolutely minimize Windows 8 data usage (for satellite phone)

Tags: windows-8, modem

What steps can I take to absolutely minimize Windows 8.1 data usage when connecting to a satellite phone? Which is $$$ per MB.

For instance

- Disable browser auto update
- Disable windows update
- Make sure Windows apps have been quit

Are there any specific hidden things to watch out for that may be using data - even minimally that wouldn't normally be a problem for metered connections but would kill a satellite 60kbps connection.

I am aware that you can set certain connections [to be metered](http://www.howtogeek.com/187483/how-to-restrict-monitor-mobile-data-usage-on-windows-8.1/) but I don't know if that would even work with a modem connection since it seems to be enabled by specifying a wi-fi network name.

Comment: Windows 8 supports metered connections.  That should do what you want.

Comment: but they're generally designed for a wi-fi hotspot where you get 5GB a month and not MB. I'm worried that there'll be lots of random services just using very small amounts of data and not even respecting the metering settings.

Comment: You might want to try it.

Comment: I'm actually asking on behalf of a friend who is about to climb Broad Peak in Pakistan (adjacent to K2) - so I'm trying to get him a list of as many things as possible

Comment: metered connection is only for WiFi. I am hoping they support modem too.